# Invalid CSRF Token in React but valid in Postman

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, csrf

I have an Express server on which I'm generating a csrf token. My **server** looks like this

```
const csrfProtection = csrf({
  cookie: {
    httpOnly: true,
  },
});
server.use(express.json());
server.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
server.use(
  cors({
    origin: "http://localhost:3000",
    credentials: true,
  })
);
server.use(cookieParser());
server.use(csrfProtection);
...
//Other routes
```

and i'm sending the token like this

```
export const csrf = (req, res) => {
  return res.send({ csrfToken: req.csrfToken() });
};
```

If I take it from the response and add it to the `X-CSRF-Token` header in Postman, then I can access all the routes just fine. But when I do it in React I always get the `invalid csrf token` error

This is how I take the token in React

```
export const getCSRFToken = async () => {
  try {
    const { data } = await axios.get("/auth/csrf");
    axios.defaults.headers.post["X-CSRF-Token"] = data.csrfToken;
  } catch (error) {}
};
```

And I'm using the `withCredentials: true` flag on other requests. I can't figure out what I'm missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the problem is that you need to pass the withCredetials flag to the request getting the csrf token too. So this fixed the problem.

```
export const getCSRFToken = async () => {
  try {
    const { data } = await axios.get("/auth/csrf", { withCredentials: true });
    axios.defaults.headers.common["X-CSRF-Token"] = data.csrfToken;
  } catch (error) {}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should change `axios.defaults.headers.post["X-CSRF-Token"] = data.csrfToken` to `axios.defaults.headers.common["X-CSRF-Token"] = data.csrfToken`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Though it didn't work. The headers and cookies are sent (I can see in the network tab when inspecting the request) but the error still occurs.